# Get tabular as well as json column in a T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, `FOR JSON PATH` allows for the whole result set returned as a JSON string. Is there a way to get a regular record set with some columns as JSON?

For e.g. for a Products (Master) and Orders (Details) table when joined together, I would like the query to return the result set from the `Products` table as regular tabular columns, but those multiple rows for each product from the `Orders` table returned as a JSON column.

Until now I have been doing this using a user-defined scalar function to which the product ID was passed and it returned JSON formatted Orders data, but I was hoping if there was a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Something like:

```
select SalesOrderId, OrderDate, TotalDue, d.Details
from SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader h
cross apply 
(
    select * 
    from SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail d
    where d.SalesOrderId = h.SalesOrderId
    for json path
)  d(details)
```

Comment: Thank you! Never thought of CROSS APPLY. I wonder if the execution plan is efficient than the inline scalar user-defined function I have been using. If nothing else, your solution helps me avoid creating UDFs in the database if there is only one time use for them.