# Call UDF with many parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating an import process where I ultimately need a SELECT of several fields along with a computed value. The logic of the computed value is rather complex, I'll need to do it in a UDF rather than in the SELECT itself.

The problem is that the computed value is determined by the contents of 30-40 columns... What I've considered:

- A monster function with 30-40 input parameters.
- Write a SP or C# app to loop through the selected data. This option is likely not as future-proof as the others.
- Passing the entire record's contents as JSON as a single parameter and pull the appropriate fields in my UDF. I'd need to combine columns and JSON in a select as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837147/get-tabular-as-well-as-json-column-in-a-t-sql-query).

Any ideas for a better solution? I'm leaning towards the last one.

To further worsen this situation is that the data is not on the server that I plan on running the UDF, and that server is older (does not support FOR JSON clause). But I can clumsily get around this part with OpenQuery().

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing multiple parameters you could pass single[TVP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) (table valued parameter).

Approach 1:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE   
( param1 VARCHAR(50)  
, param2 INT
, param3 DATE );  

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@tvp_params MyTAB)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN (
     SELECT ...
     FROM ...
     JOIN @tvp_params ...
);
```

Approach 2:

```
CREATE TYPE myEAVTableType AS TABLE
(  param_id    INT
  ,param_name VARCHAR(128)
  ,param_value SQL_VARIANT);
```

And inside of function do some sort of `PIVOT`.